# Plotting depth data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Working with a large chemistry dataset of samples collected at different depths. The data is in long format as:

```
    <Date>      <Depth> <Temp>
    2015-06-11   4 m     15
    2015-07-11   4 m     16
    2015-08-11   4 m     17
    2015-06-11   3 m     19
    2015-07-11   3 m     20
    2015-08-11   3 m     21
    2015-06-11   2 m     25
    2015-07-11   2 m     26
    2015-08-11   2 m     27
```

Trying to graph it as such that I have temperature on my x-axis and depth on my y-axis and then color them by their dates. Currently when I add a geom_line to the function it just connects all the dots.

```
    ggplot(aes(x = Temp, y = Depth, color = Date)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: That is the default behavior of `geom_line()` to connect observations in the order of the x-axis variable.  If you want to color the points by date, it might be better to use the `fill` aesthetic within `geom_point` and completely forgo any use of a line geometry.  And maybe the `alpha` aesthetic if you have overplotting.

Answer (score 0):

Connection for geoms is established typically just by applying an aesthetic as you did (`color=`).  What's actually happening there is that `ggplot` is applying the actual aesthetic (drawing the color), but will also apply a somewhat hidden aesthetic, `group=` to the same value.  Normally, this works fine unless the column you assign to `color=` is continuous (like a date), rather than a factor (which is ordinal, but discrete).  If `df$Date` is actually formatted as a `"Date"` class, then it's continuous and would exhibit behavior consistent with what you mentioned.  The fix is to either explicitly define the `group=` aesthetic in addition to `color=`, or to convert `df$Date` to a factor (discrete).

The example below using your dataset should help explain.  For exemplary purposes, I'm adding a column called `df$Other`, which is formatted as a factor.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date=rep(c('2015-06-11','2016-07-11','2015-08-11'),3),
  Other=rep(c('Jun','July','Aug'),3),
  Depth=c(4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2),
  Temp=c(15,16,17,19,20,21,25,26,27)
)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

First, here's what your code posted gives you:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Temp, y=Depth, color=Date)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Look familiar?  We know that `df$Date` is continuous, because `ggplot2` draws a legend which is continuous by default, and also because we know it is formatted as a `Date` class.  Consider what happens if you swap out `df$Other` in place of `df$Date`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Temp, y=Depth, color=Other)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Now the issue should be very clear, but how can you solve it?  Well, like I mentioned there are two approaches.  One is to maintain `df$Date` as a continuous variable, but clarify to `ggplot2` that you want to use this as a grouping variable.  In order to do so, `ggplot2` will basically convert it to a factor for purposes of connecting the lines, but keep it continuous to make the color scale:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Temp, y=Depth, color=Date)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group=Date))
```

[image]

One of the best options might be to set `df$Date` as a factor with ordered levels, since you're not actually using the "Date" class's continuous nature anyway.  You can actually just use `color=factor(Date)` to fix it right in-line, but you'll notice that the levels are not going to be correct (in terms of the months in the correct order).  In this case, I'd recommend changing the column prior to plotting using `factor()` and setting the levels there.  Here's my solution:

```
# convert to character vector first
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)
# it's already in the correct order, so just use the order of the df
df$Date <- factor(df$Date, levels=unique(df$Date))

ggplot(df, aes(x=Temp, y=Depth, color=Date)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]